# React Route V6 Get Navigation history

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Using React Router V6, how do I get the user's navigation history?

I'm almost certain this is a duplicate but I cannot seem to find anything on React Router's Documentation, their Github and even here mentioning how I should find where the user has been in my app. My only other option is use the browser history but its not perfect for my use case.

EDIT
The use case is analytics and the ability to navigate to the last point of interest, for instance if the user visits a product, the  login page then, the add address page then I'd want the next page they access be the product which is now 2 pages down the stack.

Comment: What "history" are you trying to track? You can't access the browser's full history stack, and you are correct in that RRD doesn't provide anything like this out-the-box. Can you [edit] the post to clarify the use case, and any coding implementation you've tried already? In all likelihood you'll need to roll your own history stack object if you want to track where a user's gone within your app.

Comment: Regarding your edit I don't think you need to know any of the history stack for those use cases. Do you have a more specific programming issue that you can share a [mcve] of? As-is your question is too broad and likely not on-topic for Stackoverflow.

Comment: Yea, if a react router solution does not exist then this may be a feature request sort of thing.
About your mention that I don't need the browser history for my use cases do you have any specific alternatives on how I could achieve this.

Comment: Well, I don't know why analytics would need access to the history stack save for a sort of "stack trace" where a user navigated, but this is easily accomplished by sending when each page is accessed and the "history" can be derived from the data. In the case of auth redirects, well, use redirects (i.e. REPLACE) between pages/steps instead of PUSH actions and when the user clicks back, they go back to the page they were on prior to starting an "auth flow". In other words the app is simply manipulating the current entry on the stack. Does this make sense?